# How to specify the size of a text box in a panel?

Tags: python, panel

Please consider the following image:

[image: Bad length]

The text box with the value "127.0.0.1:56661" is just too big, it occupies a considerable percentage of the row in the panel leaving small space for the label "Some parameter". How can I specify the text box size?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the property name of the text box (name = "",) and add a row.label(text="Some Parameter: ") above your row.prop(scene "Parameter Op String Box") in your panel build.